# Best to use: mysql column or file check to detect image?

Tags: mysql, performance, filesystems, disk-access

I always have a dilema: For a record, I can use column images (tinyint) that is true if there is image for that record or false if there is not.

I can also not put that information in the database and in my code I "snoop" with disk filesystem check if the image exists.

Both give the same results of course. Having in database means maintaining the image state separately from the real image on disk, means harder to program and more prone to errors (disk image is not there any more, in the database the record has true on column image).

So I use disk check usually. But it occured to me, maybe this has a hard penalty on the disk access. I know database check must be faster, I have to get the record off the database anyway. But is looking for image using filesystem as bad as it occured to me or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros for storing it in the database:

- You can create queries that answer questions like "Give me all objects that have no image"
- Its much faster as you do not have to touch the disk

I can see no pros for only storing it on disk. Use a pattern with a "single place of responsibility", meaning that only one place in your code saves, updates, deletes images. In this place you update the file and the database. Done this way, its not very prone for errors.

Put the other way round: if this makes your application prone for errors, you should check your architecture.

Comment: Thanx. I agree. Could be some problem on the server and the DB is deleted and the image isn't for example... But yes, it is better this way.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion checking on the disk is wasteful and a bit of bad practice. The DB should hold this, because:

- It is much faster.
- A lookup on the disk which does not retrieve the
  wanted record should be seen as an error (which can also be taken
  care of elegantly, of course).

Maintaining the column shouldn't be too much fuss, as you maintain the name of the file anyway, right? So when the filename is updated this column should also be updated accordingly.

Comment: It's not that maintaining the column in the database would be a lot of work, but looking at the flag in a database record is not guaranteed to indicate if there's actually an image file there, while looking at the filesystem is directly testing whether the image is there or not.  Unless you're already hitting the database for some other reason, there shouldn't be a big performance difference, since both are likely to be cached in memory (at least under UNIX/Linux)

Comment: @dj_segfault - I assume he is hitting the DB anyway to get the image name/path. I think in this case if the DB says there should be an image and there isn't, you don't want the system to simply ignore this and go on - you would want to know and investigate what happened.

Comment: As there is only one image the image names is the id field + "jpg". I am checking the file using classic ASP / filesystem object, not with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Are the images more likely to be there or more likely not to be there? If you're seeing if the file exists will you *always* use the file?

If the answer to both is "yes", then by all means, use the disk. If you have reason to believe that it will be there the overwhelming majority of the time, then use `@file` and handle a FALSE return (especially since file_exists can have cross-platform implementation issues). I'd consider this to be more than adequate practice.

If not, then you need to look at your program flow:

Ask database -- does file exist?

- yes = fetch file.

  - If file is not really needed do something assuming file exists
  - else fetch file => has the file fetch succeeded? (you're doing this check even with the DB query)

    - yes = do something with file
    - no = update db and do something without file.
- no = do something without file. (when will file existence be updated? cron?)

If you plan on using the file, you *have* to check for the file if the DB says its there which means that the only time that you can optimize with use of a DB is when the file itself is not needed.